# Counts and percentages for overlapping categories in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, categorical-data

I am trying to summarise sets of overlapping categories from a "here are 10 categories, pick 3" survey question. Each category has a value if they picked it and an NA if they didn't.  Here is a dummy example with 3 categories:

```
P_A<-c("A","A",NA,NA)
P_B<-c(NA,"B","B",NA)
P_C<-c("C", NA, NA,NA)
grouper<-c("M", "M", "F","F")
data.df<-data.frame(P_A,P_B,P_C,grouper)
```

I am trying to create a table that shows total number select and percentage (count over number of people that selected at least one option), then also be able to subdivide by a covariate. Eg. the following table or two versions of the following table for M and F (but could be more than 2 categories in the grouper). Note, in my example, the 4th row is someone who selected no categories so is not part of the denominator for the percentage.

| Variable | Overall count | Overall % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P_A | 2 | 66.67 |
| P_B | 2 | 66.67 |
| P_C | 1 | 33.33 |

I can produce the figures using `colSums(!isna(select(data.df, P_A:P_C)))` and then dividing by `sum(rowSums(!is.na(select(data.df, P_A:P_C)))>0)` but I'm struggling to make that more generalisable for other variables and am not sure how to neatly do it when I want separate tables by the grouper variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the rows with all `NA` values, get the data in long format and for each column find number and percentage of non-NA values.

```
library(dplyr)

data.df %>%
  select(-grouper) %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns =  ~!is.na(.)))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(!is.na(value)), 
            overall_perc = count/n() * 100)

#  name  count overall_perc
#  <chr> <int>        <dbl>
#1 P_A       2         66.7
#2 P_B       2         66.7
#3 P_C       1         33.3
```

---

To do this for each category of `grouper` you could do :

```
data.df %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`, across(-grouper, ~!is.na(.)))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -grouper) %>%
  group_by(name, grouper) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(!is.na(value)), 
            overall_perc = count/n() * 100)
```

Comment: Thanks. How about if I want separate figures for each category of grouper?

Comment: I've never thought of using `across()` as an argument to `Reduce()`, that's pretty slick.